# Composite Galois Extensions and germs

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, sheaf-theory

I'm reading through some Dummit and Foote chapters on Galois theory and came across this proposition.

> Proposition 21. Let $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be Galois extensions of a field $F$. Then
>
> (1) The intersection $K_{1} \cap K_{2}$ is Galois over F
>
> (2) The composite $K_{1}K_{2}$ is Galois over $F$. The Galois group is isomorphic to the subgroup
>
> $H = \{(\sigma, \tau) | \sigma|_{K_{1}\cap K_{2}} = \tau|_{K_{1} \cap K_{2}}\}$ of
>
> of the direct product of $Gal(K_{1}/F) \times Gal(K_{2}/F)$

That subgroup $H$ seems very much like a collection of germs to me, is there some relation between Galois groups and sheaves?

Comment: No connections to sheaves there. If you want to put this into an abstract context, $H$ is just a pull back in the categorical sense.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you!